# Distinct Linq filtering with additional criteria

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have a list which contains duplicate item values (by ID), but with a different (or possibly equal) priority. Duplicate items with same or lower priority should be removed from the list.

For example:

```
var items = new {
   new { Id=2, Priority=3 },
   new { Id=4, Priority=4 },
   new { Id=1, Priority=4 },
   new { Id=2, Priority=5 },
   new { Id=4, Priority=4 }
};

RemoveDuplicates(items);

// items should now contain distinct values,
// with highest possible priority
var items = new {
   new { Id=1, Priority=4 }, // this one was unique
   new { Id=2, Priority=5 }, // this one was duplicate with higher priority
   new { Id=4, Priority=4 }, // this one was duplicate with same priority
};
```

Is it possible to do this using LINQ? I know I could sort the list by ID and then check adjacent items, but just wanted to check if this is possible.

(update: input values are not necessarily grouped by IDs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
        var items = new[] {
           new { Id=2, Priority=3 },
           new { Id=2, Priority=5 },
           new { Id=1, Priority=4 },
           new { Id=4, Priority=4 },
           new { Id=4, Priority=4 }
        };

        var deduped = items
            .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
            .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(item => item.Priority).First())
            .OrderBy(item => item.Id);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Distinct Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) returns the distinct elements from a sequence. You can provide an IEqualityComparer<TSource> to determine when two elements are equal. However, the method does not allow you to choose which of the two equal elements is used.

You can use the [GroupBy Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) to group the list by ID and then select the element with the highest priority from each group:

```
var query = items.GroupBy(item => item.Id)
                 .Select(g => g.MaxBy(item => item.Priority))
                 .OrderBy(item => item.Id);
```

using MaxBy from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).